# How to tell PIP that pyspark has already been installed?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, pip, manual

I installed a custom-built version of Spark, and set SPARK_HOME and PYTHON_PATH to the corresponding folders, as per [this guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/getting_started/install.html#manually-downloading)

Then I used pip to install some python package, which has pyspark as a dependency, hence I got two versions of pyspark installed - my custom-built pyspark, and the one from PyPI.

Is there any way to make this not happen?

Thanks!

Comment: How did you install that "custom-built" spark? Because to be recognized by pip, you should've done it via pip - and after that, it would be normally recognized while installing dependencies

Comment: I got a spark.tgz distribution file, similar to the ones from this page https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html. However, it has some customized functionality. Also, it has Spark (scala), Spark-SQL,..., not only Pyspark

Comment: Unpack it and find where setup.py is located. Go to the dir and run `pip install .` (https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/#installing-from-source)

Comment: Thanks. I did that, but the files are still got duplicated (from the original location to the python installation location). For now I'm running `pip install -e .`, not sure whether that will have any bad consequence

Comment: They will get duplicated because python itself only checks for locations specified in pythonpath, not random places on your drive - so installing a package runs the install and puts everything in correct location. `-e` flag means development and that any change you do to your source will be reflected when importing

Comment: Thanks. I didn't want it to duplicate because I'm going to use my image in AWS ECS, and the size of the image affect the startup time of the ECS task